# Google Apps Scripts Table - cannot add inner table to a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create tables on a blank document. My issue is that I cannot create a table within a cell even though the documentation says it is possible with appendTable(). The code below fails on the last line with error "Service unavailable:Docs". Thanks.

```
function buildInvoice() {

//create new document
var doc = DocumentApp.create('MyWorld');

doc.appendParagraph("That's it!");

var body = doc.getBody();

var table = body.appendTable();
var table3 = body.appendTable();
var tr_header = table.appendTableRow();
var td_header = tr_header.appendTableCell("Heading");
td_header.setBackgroundColor("#CFCFCF");
var row1 = table.appendTableRow();
var cell1 = row1.appendTableCell("cell 1");
var cell2 = row1.appendTableCell();
cell2.appendTable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a bug, there is an open issue with a workaround discussed here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=894#c2

Comment: Thanks Cameron. Do you know of any other possible way to build a custom invoice or report using Google Docs and Google Apps Scripts?

Comment: I would suggest trying to use Google Sheets as much as possible. For an invoice, typically I would create a template spreadsheet with the layout all set up, then create copies of that template, update the cells for the invoice number, date, etc.  And then I would insert rows into the sheet for any line items on the invoice.